# Why does app crash when text is deleted from textField while checking if username exists in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

As the user is typing in a new user name on the registration screen, the text in `userNameTextField` is checked against Firebase Realtime Database to make sure that the username isn't already taken. Works great!

If you just delete a letter or two after you begin typing, no problem. But if you delete all the letters after starting to type, the iOS simulator crashes. Here's the code:

```
@IBAction func userNameTextFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (user, error) in

        if let error = error
        {
            self.showMessage(messageToDisplay: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if user != nil {
            var databaseReference: DatabaseReference!
            databaseReference = Database.database().reference()
            Database.database().reference().child("allUsers").child(self.userNameTextField.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(usernameSnap) in

                if usernameSnap.exists(){
                    self.userNameStatusLabel.text = "Username is already taken."
                    self.nextButton.isEnabled = false
                    self.nextButton.alpha = 0.25
                } else{
                    self.userNameStatusLabel.text = ""
                }

            })
        }   
    }
}
```

After the app crashes, it shows me the AppDelegate in Xcode with the message

> "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" after the line "class AppDelegate:
>   UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {"

In the debug area below, the message reads

> "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)"

Any idea why it is crashing and how to fix it? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint so you can get proper details on the crash.

Comment: I'll study up on what that means and be back soon with better details. Thank you!

Comment: Press `⌘8`, then clicked on the `+` at lower left, select `Exception breakpoint...`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are getting

> Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'

which means in your case you are sending an empty string with firebase which is not possible.